# Python UUID endiannes confusion

Tags: python, uuid, endianness

I'm using *uuid* package in *Python*. *RFC 4122* says that "the UUID
   record definition is defined only in terms of fields that are
   integral numbers of octets.".

However when I play with endianness (*bytes* and *bytes_le*) I can see that not all fields of uuid are converted:

```
>>> hx(uuid.UUID("d535fc02-e74f-5015-b8c9-a3b89d760ecd").bytes_le)
b'02fc35d54fe71550>>THIS>>b8c9a3b89d760ecd<<'
>>> hx(uuid.UUID("d535fc02-e74f-5015-b8c9-a3b89d760ecd").bytes)
b'd535fc02e74f5015>>THIS>>b8c9a3b89d760ecd<<'
```

In the output above it can be seen that the last 8 bytes don't change regardless of the endianness of UUID representation.

Now, let's suppose the target machine is little-endian, we receive UUID in big-endian byte order (acc. to RFC) and have to convert it to inner representation, that is parse it's fields to integers according to the platform representation.

**What bytes should I reverse?**  Should I reverse only time low, time mid and time high and version, with clock seq and node remaining untouched?

Answer (score 2):

The UUID is send in big-endian byte order. It is up to the platform to convert to the local endianness so you can use the `UUID.fields` tuple. The first 3 fields should be converted so you can use it as integers.

The same goes for the creation of the UUID. You don't specify the endianness of the `fields` tuple because the platform already knows.

The last 8 bytes are not converted because they are not multi byte numbers. They are 2 one byte clock values and a string of 6 bytes describing the node.